# Bootstrap radio group change background colour if checked

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a group radio button which has four options. When the script runs the group is populated by the result of an Ajax call. This works fine, but I am trying to change the background colour of the checked radio option using "removeClass" and "addClass". My code does not work, can anyone see where I am going wrong.

The code I am working with is:

```js
var rl = 1; //result[17];
if (rl == 1) {
  $('#EditRoomLevel_1').prop('checked', true);
  if ($('#EditRoomLevel_1').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditRoomLevel_1").removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label').addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
  }
}
```

```css
.btn-primary {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0.5px solid #CCC !important;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.btn-primary-conf {
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #B7FFBA;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 175px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 13px;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: 0.5px solid #CCC !important;
  margin-top: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">Name, text and logo<span class="rhidden"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="EditRoomLevel" id="EditRoomLevel_1" value="1"></span></label>
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label ">Name and logo<span class="rhidden"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="EditRoomLevel" id="EditRoomLevel_2" value="2"></span></label>
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label">Name only<span class="rhidden"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="EditRoomLevel" id="EditRoomLevel_3" value="3" ></span></label>
<label class="btn btn-primary form-check-label">Logo only<span class="rhidden"><input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="EditRoomLevel" id="EditRoomLevel_4" value="4" ></span></label>
```

Many thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: We need to see a working example including your HTML and CSS in order to help you debug this. However, I can tell you that your `if` condition will *always* be true, as you set the element as `checked` in the line before. Also note that this could potentially be done more effectively in CSS alone.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Hi Rory, I have added the HTML and the CSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var rl = 1; //result[17];
if (rl == 1) {
  $('#EditRoomLevel_1').prop('checked', true);
  if ($('#EditRoomLevel_1').is(':checked')) {
    $("#EditRoomLevel_1").parent().parent().removeClass('btn btn-primary form-check-label').addClass('btn btn-primary-conf form-check-label');
  }
}
```

You are trying to remove and add classes on an element that should not have them,but his parent's parent should have it, the label.

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks for your time. I am now going to read up on "parent()".

Answer (score 1):

To change background color on changing radio button value try below code

```
$(".form-check-input").change(function() {
        if(this.checked) {
            if ($('.form-check-input:checked').length > 0) {
        var id = $('input[type=radio][name=EditRoomLevel]:checked').attr('id');
            $('label').removeClass('btn-primary-conf').addClass('btn-primary');
            $("#"+id).closest('label').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-primary-conf');
        }

        }
    });
```